# How to return a readable result from Postgres function by SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm calling a Postgres function from Flask-SQLAlchemy. The function returns a table with 2 values: string and number:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test (
  id varchar
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  project_name varchar,
  projects_num integer
) AS
$body$
DECLARE 
BEGIN    
...
RETURN QUERY (SELECT project.name as project_name, project_nums as projects_num);   
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

On the Flask side I'm doing the following call:

```
engine = create_engine(url)
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute('SELECT "test"(\'123\')').fetchone()
```

Then I'm trying to get data from result.

```
for row in result:
    print(literal_eval(row))
```

This throws the exception because actually row has a string:

```
(my_project, 3)
```

And of course, it doesn't know what the heck is my_project. How to make it return results correctly or handle them correctly? For example it could return `('my_project', 3)`

I solved this problem added parentheses

```
('"' || account_object.valid_status || '"')
```

But it looks awful and can't believe there is no normal way to solve? 
Another problem with Null - it just isn't included in the tuple: `(,0)` - how is supposed to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string value is the representation of a Postgresql composite (row) value, and as such is clearly not meant to be evaluated as a Python literal. Psycopg2 can handle and adapt composite type values to Python values, but that requires using a created type. In your case the simple solution is to select from the table valued function, instead of using it as a select list item:

```
result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM "test"(\'123\')').fetchone()
print(result.project_name, result.projects_num)
```